# LDO has no output

Tags: capacitor, ldo

I've been trying to get a fixed output LDO to work for the past few hours, in order to step 3.6 V down to 3.3 V, but I have been unsuccessful. I am using the [MCP1824T-3302E/OT](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/37930.pdf) LDO.

I have it wired up very similarly to the diagram on the third page. I am using a 3.6 V Li-po battery and I have its voltage and ground connected to V<sub>IN</sub> and GND(TAB), I have a 1 µF capacitor connected between V<sub>IN</sub> and GND(TAB) (the sample diagram uses a 4.7 µF capacitor, but later in the documentation it says anything between 1 and 10 µF is fine and I am out of 4.7 µF capacitors at the moment), I have SHDN wired to the input voltage, and I am using a 1 µF capacitor as the output capacitor. I'm pretty sure that I have every component that I need attached, but my multimeter reads nothing from the V<sub>OUT</sub> pin no matter what.

If it matters, [these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/311625786797?lpid=82&chn=ps&ul_noapp=true) are the kind of capacitors I'm using.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Here is a picture of my setup:

[image]

Comment: Time for a photo of your layout?

Comment: You should also mention what load, if any, is connected to the LDO output.

Comment: Are you certain it's the microchip version of the ic, instead of another brand which may have different pinout? Does the lipo work?

Comment: The battery is 3.6 V, and my multimeter confirms that. I bought the chip from arrow, and the label on the bag says that it's the chip that I expected it to be, so I'm fairly sure it is the right IC. Here is an image - http://imgur.com/a/DXE6p. Could someone edit my post to add the image? I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links.

Comment: The soldering does not look so good. In particular the Vout terminal: I can see the wire across the solder bump. This can lead to a cold solder.  Also it looks like you might have been at it with the soldering iron for a while can could have damaged the chip.  The solder should be tightly bonded to the wires, and not 'beading' off.  Add more flux, solder, and let the wire get hot.  Don't try to heat the solder and then drip it onto the wire.  Heat the wire (by putting solder on the iron tip, touching the tip to the wire) and then apply solder to the wire/solder tip interface. Remove old solder

Comment: The cold-joint issues mentioned by @jbord39 can (mostly) be verified by measuring on the actual pins on the component, apart from intermittent issues and overheating.

Comment: Unless the chip was damaged by heat during this soldering job.

Comment: What Jbord39 said, plus those caps are too far from the IC. Plus no load (add a 10 mA led + resistor setup). That said, you should still see a voltage out unless you have a bad solder connection or damaged the IC. Check for continuity on all pins and wires,  with the battery off. Or get a proper breakout board.

Comment: Looks like there is about 6-10 inches of wire between the IC and the capacitors. That can be a problem, as the long wires have series inductance. The capacitors won't be effective as bypass capacitors, unless they are close to the IC pins.

Comment: One online place to buy surface-mount prototyping boards is www.capitaladvanced.com ("surfboards". Note that shopping questions arr off-topic but I mention this as a diagnostic). Something like that would be easier to solder, and would have a place to mount bypass capacitors.

Comment: @pipe As you suggested, I measured the voltage across the Vin and GND pin on the actual chip and I got 3.6 V. I actually don't know if I am soldering it to the board I made improperly- I was sure to not keep the soldering iron to the pin of the IC for no more than 1-2 seconds at a time. I also checked for continuity with my multimeter as passerby suggested and each pin of the chip tests positive for continuity with the ends of the wire.

Comment: @MarkU - The documentation calls them input and output capacitors, not bypass capacitors. What's the difference? Just curious. I'll try to get the capacitors on the board itself and see what happens.

Comment: @R_Misra I'm glad you're following the advice given by the commenters, a lot of askers start to argue instead. This increases both your chances of solving the problem, and of getting more helpful answers.

Comment: "I measured the voltage across the Vin and GND pin on the actual chip and I got 3.6 V." - at 3.6V your Lipo battery is flat, and needs charging. If it has a protection circuit (hard to tell from your photo, but I think I can see one in it) then drawing current may cause it to cut off.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I can't find the link of where I bought it, but they were definitely advertised as being 3.6 V batteries. What voltage did you think the battery was, or did you make some other assumption? (Of course, I could just be wrong/misunderstanding you.) And you are right about the protection circuit. There are 2 IC's under the yellow wrapping.

Comment: This part has pad underneath that is tied to ground, maybe some solder got underneath from one of your joints?  Try an ohm-meter between each pin and ground.

Comment: "they were definitely advertised as being 3.6 V batteries"- Many vendors are selling '3.6V' Lipos that are actually 3.7V (fully charged at 4.2V, 90% discharged at 3.7V). What does it say on the battery?

Comment: Oh, you're right! It says 3.7 on the battery. Luckily I have a charging board, so I'll use that right away. You guys are giving me so much to do haha

Comment: @JohnBirckhead I just checked the underside of one of my spare IC's and it is completely black, so I think you're thinking about the SOT-223-3? I am using the SOT-23-5 version of the LDO. Nevertheless, I tried using an ohmmeter and got O.L for each pin except Vout, but that was .531 megaohms.

Comment: You are correct; apologies. I was just trying to think of something because nothing you have done seems to be bad enough to give you no voltage at the output.  I'm thinking the part is dead.  If you rebuild, you might want to consider tying /SHDN to Vin at the board to prevent any chance of having V(shdn) > Vin.  Also it is good to have a load so that the output doesn't have to be discharged backwards through the part at power down, or put a reverse biased diode across vout and vin.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead If the output was discharged backward through the part at power down, would that permanently damage it? I did try it earlier with a simple LED/resistor, but that yielded no results as well. However, I tried it with no load before that, so if that broke it that might explain why it's been giving me no output. I haven't managed to stick the capacitors on the board yet so that they're closer to the IC, but I'm beginning to feel like that would just improve the smoothness of the signal and not fix a complete lack of output.

Comment: Also, does anyone know what type of capacitor that is in my picture? I've googled it but I can't find it.

Comment: It depends on the instantaneous current.  These very low power devices are not very tolerant of current at any time.  When unloaded, the charge on your output cap has nowhere else to go.  The linear regulators are designed to have current flow in one direction.  Also be careful of having power become disconnected when SHDN is still attached.

Comment: To everyone here- I think I know what my problem was. I wasn't using any sort of electrostatic protection when I took the IC from its bag to the board before I soldered it. I thought that wouldn't have an effect, but now I'm pretty sure that I just fried the chip way before I even soldered it.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 possible sources of the problem:

1 - Cold solder joints (little soldering experience)

2 - IC damaged

3 - No load resistor

Comment: Already tested for cold solder joints. I was just testing for an output by measuring the voltage between Vout and ground- do you mean that I would have to put a resistor between Vout and ground in order to get an output in the first place? John said "it is good to have a load so that the output doesn't have to be discharged backwards through the part at power down"- is this what you mean?